# How should I save UUID with JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, uuid

How should I work with UUID and JPA?

Should I assign the random UUID value to a String field in my class? Or should I have a field with type UUID and do something else to it when I want to map it to a column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best (most efficient) DataType to use for UUIDs as JPA IDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730788/best-most-efficient-datatype-to-use-for-uuids-as-jpa-ids)

Comment: @MattBall >However, your coding efficiency would suffer, because you have to write a custom type.- from answer in that post. What does he mean?

Comment: I think what the author of the post that @MattBall references means when he says 'coding efficiency would suffer' is that each Entity that uses the UUID key would required the kind of type converter referred to  in zaske's linked post.  Thus, those Entities would have to be created by the developer rather than generated due to the use of the custom type converter.

Comment: @SteveHall Oh, I see. Thanks Steve for your explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the database. 
There are databases such as H2, MSSQL and PostgreSQL that support a uniqueidentifer type. 
For these types you can extend the provided Dialect (i.e - [PostgreSQLDialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQLDialect.html)) and add handling of the new type. 
I implemented something like that, based on the following [post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?71508-JPA-with-PostgreSQL-and-UUID-%28Hibernate%29) , for both MSSQL and Postgresql. 
For databases that do not support a uniqueidentifier/UUID type, you should use String. 
This means that you should also ask yourself if your application must support multiple database vendors, or if you can stick with a single vendor 
(and then select the first option, if applicable).